# Logic Error in C Program on xcode

Tags: c, xcode, logic

I have written this code for a grocery store.. This code makes perfect sense to me. However, I keep getting a logic error. Every time the user enters a bill and then presses -1 to exit, he is taken back to the main menu. When user presses choice 2 to EXIT program, the program is NOT exiting and he taken back to case 1 for some reason. Could you please help me? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    double prices[7];
    prices[0]=2.55;
    prices[1]=12.07;
    prices[2]=2.00;
    prices[3]=0.55;
    prices[4]=5.35;
    prices[5]=8.65;
    prices[6]=2.55;
    int choice;
    int productCode;
    int quantity;
    char stop[3];
    int compare;
    double price;
    double totalPrice=0;

    do{
        printf("\n1. Create new bill");
        printf("\n2. EXIT");
        printf("\n\nEnter choice: ");
        choice=scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 1:{
                do{
                    printf("\nEnter product code: ");
                    scanf("%d",&productCode);
                    printf("\nEnter quantity of product: ");
                    scanf("%d",&quantity);
                    price=prices[productCode]*quantity;
                    totalPrice=totalPrice+price;
                    printf("\nTo stop entering products enter -1.. to continue press any other character ");
                    scanf("%s", &stop);
                    compare=strcmp(stop, "-1");
                }while(compare!=0);
                break;
            }
            case 2: break;

            default: printf("\nInvalid choice");
        }
    }while(choice!=2);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug: Add breakpoints, display variable values, trace the execution.

Comment: Instead of breaking you should use return, in this case "case 2:" should return 0 to end the program

Comment: "Every time the user enters a bill and then presses -1 to exit, he is taken back to the main menu". The `break` in a `case` block will exit the enclosing `switch`. In your case that will then continue the `do` loop by evaluating `while(choice!=2)`. That condition is true since `choice` is `1`. Hence main menu gets printed again.

Comment: @kaylum the problem is not about the main menu being re printed again.. its about the fact that I pressed number 2 to exit and the program did not exit. It went back into case 1 instead. Thanks for trying to help though! :)

Comment: You should also check if the product code is in range before `price=prices[productCode]*quantity;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
choice=scanf("%d", &choice);
```

Do

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

`scanf` return value is:

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.
>
> If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the
>   function sets errno to EILSEQ.
>   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

```
for (;;){

    printf("\n1. Create new bill");
    printf("\n2. EXIT");
    printf("\n\nEnter choice: ");

    scanf("%d", &choice); 

    if(choice == 2 ){
        break;
    } else if(choice == 1){

        do{

            printf("\nEnter product code: ");
            scanf("%d",&productCode);
            printf("\nEnter quantity of product: ");
            scanf("%d",&quantity);
            price=prices[productCode]*quantity;
            totalPrice=totalPrice+price;
            printf("\nTo stop entering products enter -1.. to continue press any other character ");
            scanf("%s", &stop);
            compare=strcmp(stop, "-1");

        }while(compare!=0);

    } else {
        printf("\nInvalid choice");
    }

}
```